# Multiple Inputs in Shiny Not Displaying

Tags: r, shiny

I want to put in multiple inputs in the UI, but only the first is displaying when I run the app. I see other shiny code uses multiple inputs that seem to work fine and I am at a total loss as to why my selectInput("input2") is not displaying. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

data1 <- read.csv("CollegeScorecardMarch.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Two input variables
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("2 Variable Plot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("input1", "Variable 1",
          choices = c("npt4_pub", "md_earn_wne_p6"),
  selectInput("input2", "Variable 2",
          choices = c("npt4_pub", "md_earn_wne_p6"))
  )
  ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You just placed a paranthesis wrong. Try indenting your code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in RStudio) to avoid such mistakes

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

#data1 <- read.csv("CollegeScorecardMarch.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Two input variables
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("2 Variable Plot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("input1", "Variable 1",
                  choices = c("npt4_pub", "md_earn_wne_p6")),
      selectInput("input2", "Variable 2",
                  choices = c("npt4_pub", "md_earn_wne_p6")
      )
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, function(...){})
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Please accept this answer unless there is something I missed.